# How do I copy file folder contents while preserving folder structure?

Tags: osx, rsync, mv

I am working on a Mac OS El Capitan system. I have my music folders in an iTunes library that looks like this:

```
/Volumes/Public/Shared Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Artist1/Album1/file1
```

How do I move all the files but maintaining the `Artist/Album` folder structure to to the folder Shared Music so that it looks like this.

```
/Volumes/Public/Shared Music/Artist1/Album1/file1
```

I have tried `rsync -av` and it seems to be working but it's also going very slowly.

P.S. I'm using a bash shell in the terminal.

Comment: `cp -a "/Volumes/Public/Shared Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/"* "/Volumes/Public/Shared Music/"`

Comment: Are the quotation marks necessary?

Comment: So I tried this: and I got the following error:

/Volumes/Public/Shared Music/Album1/filename: fchmod failed: No such file or directory

But it should be creating the folder 
/Volumes/PUblic/Shared Music/*Artist1*/Album1/filename

Comment: It looks like you just want to move all file up two directory levels. Modern shells should handle any files with characters such as spaces. Can you not simply do `cd "/Volumes/Public/Shared Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/"` and then `mv -i * ../../` ?

Comment: That's right, that's all I want to do. Is there a way to test this before I do it on the whole file structure?